# Can't find element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to find the `a href` element and return its contents.

Here are the contents in the source:

```
<div id="responseDiv" style="background-color:#EBECED;width: 450px;">
<iframesrc="/iframe.asp" width="575" height="120" frameborder="0" 
marginwidth="1" marginheight="1" scrolling="no">
#document
<html>
<head> </head>
<body marginwidth="1" marginheight="1">
<font size="3" style = "letter-spacing: 0pt" color="#336699" face="Arial"
<a href="blablabla?subject=blebleble" target="_blank">merkl@gmail.com</a>
</font>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Tried printing outerHTML of the Div, which is the only element I can find:

```
IWebElement pisso = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="responseDiv"]"));
string outerHTML = pisso.GetAttribute("outerHTML");
```

But it doesn't return the href contents, only this:

```
<div id="responseDiv" style="background-color:#EBECED;width: 450px;">

<iframe src="/iframe.asp" width="575" height="120" frameborder="0" marginwidth="1" marginheight="1" scrolling="no">
  &lt;p&gt;Your browser does not support iframes.&lt;/p&gt;</iframe>

</div>
```

I've tried finding the href element directly but it can't find it, CssSelector as:

```
IWebElement pisso = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > font > a"));
```

Also tried XPath as:

```
 IWebElement pisso = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/font/a"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the attribute value via `.getAttribute(value)`, which returns a `String`.

So try this:

```
String hrefValue = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#responseDiv body font a")).getAttribute("href");
```

Comment: It returned can't find that element exception

Comment: Is the element visible? Or in a popup?

Comment: looks to be in an iFrame, so you will need to switch to that iFrame.

Comment: I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

The `WebElement` from which you are trying to extract the `href` attribute i.e. `blablabla?subject=blebleble` is within an `iframe` so you have to switch to the `iframe` first then search/find the element to extract the `href` attribute as follows:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@src='/iframe.asp']));
IWebElement pisso = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/font/a"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the other elements were not getting printed because the program pulling the OuterHTML too fast, before it being generated.

Solved by using:

```
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

This way it printed everything inside the Div